# Is Rama mantra made up of two mantras?

Tags: mantras, rama

I have heard that Rama is mantra of two Mantras. **Ra** from `Om namo naRayana` and **Ma** from `Om NaMah Shivay`. Is this true?

Comment: Pls read the shankara bhasyA on Vishnu sahasranama. Shankara gives the meaning of Rama as the supreme who is always in Ultimate bliss. This Ra and ma from Narayana and Shiva mantra has no basis in puranas or scriptures. Thyagaraja, who has written kirtanas on Rama might have said this. But, there is no basis to it

Comment: The justification is that If you remove "Ra" from narayana mantra, it becomes namo Nayana and if "Ma" is removed from namah Shivaya, it becomes nah Shivaya, that is no shiva or not shiva or Shiva doesnt exist. So, they say Ra and Ma are important for these two mantras. But, you can also make Rama from other mantras. So, this theory of Rama from those two mantras has no basis in any scriptures, as far as, i know.

Comment: Such things should not be trusted, because like that there can be so many possibilities in all the Mantras. Jokingly/Seriously some people say that, in "Om namo .." the `NaMo` belongs to [Narendra Modi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narendra_Modi)! But if such lie is repeated many times, then people might feel it true.

Comment: @Krishna The meaning Adi Shankaracharya gives is a perfectly valid reason for calling Vishnu Rama, but I don't think that was Dasharatha's motivation in naming his son.  I think the name was chosen for a more prosaic reason.  The Sanskrit word Rama also means charming.  Perhaps that was Dasharatha's intended meaning.

Comment: @Krishna You should convert your comment into an answer. Your comment answers the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is. Ra is agni beeja and Ma is amrita beeja. It was Sage Vasishtha who christened Rama, just as Sage Garga christened Krishna. Actions performed by sages of their calibre have multiple obvious and esoteric (mantra-related) import.

Meanings of Rama's name are discussed in rAma tApanyOpanishad.

"Râmeti dvyaksharo mantrah panchâshtâksharasâratah |
sarvâdhikârasiddhyartham vihitah kalitârakah || 6 ||"

Translation:

The two-lettered mantra "Rama" is the essence of the panchakshari (i.e. namah sivAya) and the ashtashakri (Om namO nArAyaNAya). It bestows all gains and helps surmount the travails of kali.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35098/discussion-on-answer-by-moonstar2001-is-rama-mantra-made-up-of-two-mantras).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is true. It is clearly mentioned in fifth chapter of  **Rama Rahasya Upanishad.**

> Sanaka and other ascetics asked Hanuman: “ Tell us the meaning of Sri Rama mantra”.
>
> Hanuman replied: “Among the Rama mantras the 6-lettered is the king among them all; though as mentioned earlier they exist as one-, or two-, or three, or four, or five syllables or even as six-, or seven-, or eight, or even as many more syllables. Lord Shiva knows in essence the glory of the six-syllables (mantra): **The true meaning of the king among the Rama mantras, as well as of the eight-lettered Narayana and five-lettered Shiva mantras, is spoken of as thus: Where yogi-s revel in the 2 syllable mantra viz. ‘Ra ma’ where the ra syllable denotes fire wherein abides illumination.**

Answer (score 0):

From "shuka samhita" from narrator of shrimadbhagwat puran:-

**नायनाय यद्दतेक्षराऽष्टिकं च न शिवाय यद्विना।
मुक्तिदं भवति यद्वयोर्वशत्तादं द्वयं वयमुपासमहे किल।।**

Omiting "Ra" from om namo narayana is useless and omitting "ma" from om namah shivaya is useless. Hence, "ra" and "ma" can give salvation. That's why everyone should chant "ram"